# Get the last error number in Qt, C++

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I'm testing a function that should create and write to a file, the name of which is given as an argument to the function. The function returns false on failure. Is there any way of getting an error number like GetLastError() on windows??

Comment: Which function fails?

Comment: The function that should create and write to the file, there must be some way of finding the last error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in getting the "last" error for the file operations, you can do the following:

```
bool makeSomethingWithFile(const QString &fileName, QString *error)
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    // Perform something with the file
    // ...

    // On error
    if (file.error() != QFile::NoError) {
        *error = file.errorString();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When you call this function, just provide the error string as:

```
QString error;
if (!makeSomethingWithFile("myfile", &error)) {
    qDebug() << "The error occurred:" << error;
}
```

Well, and if you need error as a number, use `FileError` enum instead of a string.

Comment: The problem is the QFile is handled totally inside the function and it only gives back true or false, is there no general error codes like windows??

Comment: You need that globally? If yes, than define a global variable that will be updated in your function, however this approach has drawbacks.

Comment: That's a good idea. This wont have to be permanent just if I can figure out whats going wrong I will be able to fix it, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For methods of QFile class you can use the method [error](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#error) that returns an [FileError](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#FileError-enum) enum